# getPageLink() and https

Tags: ssl, prestashop

So I've recently implemented and activated SSL certification on my webshop. Now I need to change all the links on it to https:// from http://

There are a few hardcoded links on the site that I'm in the process of changing but most of the links are generated by a function that fetches the url from the PS database and I've managed to figure out that you add "true" value as argument and it will fetch the https url.

The thing is that there are a lot of diff. modules and it would take a lot of time to do such thing. So I thought there might be an easier way to do this? Some kind of configuration that will add "true" value as argument for all getPageLink() functions.

The SSL is working fine. The only thing Firefox, Chrome etc are complaining on is that some elements are not https. Any help would be appritiated.

Edit : I figured there has to be some kind of global variable that respresents the domain name. So I went to the database and found PS_SHOP_DOMAIN and PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL. From what I've been able to figure out is that PS only apply SSL on the order and account pages. But I need it for all pages. so I changed the value for PS_SHOP_DOMAIN to https://domain.com but this did not make any difference. Am I on the right path?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable SSL here:
Preferences -> General -> Enable SSL

Regards,

Comment: Yes I have the SSL is working. Our issue is that browers display exclamation mark next to our URL saying the page contain unsecure elements i.e. http:// links for instance images/js files etc. We are looking for a smooth way to convert all these to https:// so that the exclamation mark is removed.

Comment: The only solution is to isolated the various points and treat. Normally if your webmaster realizes are working well, the number of link should be low.